# Not sure if javac isn't working or i'm just dumb

Tags: java, foreach, compiler-errors, javac

Alright so I am just a simple noob trying to add my own little twist on an already-existing code. The only problem is I need to get the .java file to .class. I struggled with eclipse because I need certain packages in order to make everything work but when I put the packages in there, it just wouldn't build in general. So I gave up on eclipse and tried the javac command prompt. When I tried that it gave me this error that made no sense to me, am I just dumb or is javac not working properly?

What causes the error:

```
EnumPokemon.java:36: error: illegal start of expression
    for (EnumPokemon pokemon : ) {
                               ^
EnumPokemon.java:46: error: illegal start of expression
    for (EnumPokemon e : ) {
                         ^
EnumPokemon.java:71: error: illegal start of expression
    for (EnumPokemon e : ) {
                         ^
EnumPokemon.java:97: error: illegal start of expression
    for (EnumPokemon pokemon : ) {
```

If Someone could help a simple noob such as myself that would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Thanks for suggesting the edit, im new to java and this website so im not sure how to do that. Ill copy and paste the code RN

```
package com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.enums;

import com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.database.DatabaseHelper;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public enum EnumPokemon
{
  Abra("Abra"),  Absol("Absol"),  Aerodactyl("Aerodactyl"),  Aggron("Aggron"),  Aipom("Aipom"),  Alakazam("Alakazam"),  Altaria("Altaria"),  Ampharos("Ampharos"),  Anorith("Anorith"),  Arbok("Arbok"),  Arcanine("Arcanine"),  Arceus("Arceus"),  Archen("Archen"),  Archeops("Archeops"),  Ariados("Ariados"),  Armaldo("Armaldo"),  Aron("Aron"),  Articuno("Articuno"),  Azumarill("Azumarill"),  Bagon("Bagon"),  Bastiodon("Bastiodon"),  Bayleef("Bayleef"),  Beedrill("Beedrill"),  Beldum("Beldum"),  Bellossom("Bellossom"),  Bellsprout("Bellsprout"),  Bisharp("Bisharp"),  Blastoise("Blastoise"),  Blaziken("Blaziken"),  Blissey("Blissey"),  Boldore("Boldore"),  Braviary("Braviary"),  Bulbasaur("Bulbasaur"),  Butterfree("Butterfree"),  Camerupt("Camerupt"),  Carracosta("Carracosta"),  Carvanha("Carvanha"),  Caterpie("Caterpie"),  Celebi("Celebi"),  Chandelure("Chandelure"),  Chansey("Chansey"),  Charizard("Charizard"),  Charmander("Charmander"),  Charmeleon("Charmeleon"),  Chatot("Chatot"),  Chikorita("Chikorita"),  Chimchar("Chimchar"),  Chinchou("Chinchou"),  Clefable("Clefable"),  Clefairy("Clefairy"),  Cleffa("Cleffa"),  Cloyster("Cloyster"),  Cottonee("Cottonee"),  Cranidos("Cranidos"),  Crobat("Crobat"),  Croconaw("Croconaw"),  Crustle("Crustle"),  Combusken("Combusken"),  Corphish("Corphish"),  Corsola("Corsola"),  Cryogonal("Cryogonal"),  Cubone("Cubone"),  Crawdaunt("Crawdaunt"),  Cyndaquil("Cyndaquil"),  Delibird("Delibird"),  Dewott("Dewott"),  Dewgong("Dewgong"),  Diglett("Diglett"),  Ditto("Ditto"),  Dodrio("Dodrio"),  Doduo("Doduo"),  Donphan("Donphan"),  Dragonair("Dragonair"),  Dragonite("Dragonite"),  Drapion("Drapion"),  Dratini("Dratini"),  Drifblim("Drifblim"),  Drifloon("Drifloon"),  Drowzee("Drowzee"),  Dugtrio("Dugtrio"),  Dunsparce("Dunsparce"),  Duosion("Duosion"),  Dwebble("Dwebble"),  Eevee("Eevee"),  Ekans("Ekans"),  Electabuzz("Electabuzz"),  Electivire("Electivire"),  Electrode("Electrode"),  Elekid("Elekid"),  Emboar("Emboar"),  Emolga("Emolga"),  Empoleon("Empoleon"),  Entei("Entei"),  Espeon("Espeon"),  Exeggcute("Exeggcute"),  Exeggutor("Exeggutor"),  Farfetchd("Farfetchd"),  Fearow("Fearow"),  Feraligatr("Feraligatr"),  Flaaffy("Flaaffy"),  Flareon("Flareon"),  Flygon("Flygon"),  Forretress("Forretress"),  Galvantula("Galvantula"),  Gastly("Gastly"),  Gengar("Gengar"),  Gigalith("Gigalith"),  Girafarig("Girafarig"),  Geodude("Geodude"),  Glaceon("Glaceon"),  Gligar("Gligar"),  Gliscor("Gliscor"),  Gloom("Gloom"),  Golbat("Golbat"),  Goldeen("Goldeen"),  Golduck("Golduck"),  Golem("Golem"),  Golett("Golett"),  Golurk("Golurk"),  Graveler("Graveler"),  Grimer("Grimer"),  Grotle("Grotle"),  Groudon("Groudon"),  Grovyle("Grovyle"),  Growlithe("Growlithe"),  Gyarados("Gyarados"),  Haunter("Haunter"),  Hitmonchan("Hitmonchan"),  Hitmonlee("Hitmonlee"),  Hitmontop("Hitmontop"),  Honchkrow("Honchkrow"),  Hoothoot("Hoothoot"),  Houndoom("Houndoom"),  Houndour("Houndour"),  Horsea("Horsea"),  Hypno("Hypno"),  Igglybuff("Igglybuff"),  Infernape("Infernape"),  Ivysaur("Ivysaur"),  Jigglypuff("Jigglypuff"),  Jolteon("Jolteon"),  Joltik("Joltik"),  Jynx("Jynx"),  Kabuto("Kabuto"),  Kadabra("Kadabra"),  Kabutops("Kabutops"),  Kakuna("Kakuna"),  Kangaskhan("Kangaskhan"),  Kingdra("Kingdra"),  Kingler("Kingler"),  Klang("Klang"),  Klink("Klink"),  Klinklang("Klinklang"),  Koffing("Koffing"),  Krabby("Krabby"),  Krokorok("Krokorok"),  Krookodile("Krookodile"),  Kyogre("Kyogre"),  Lairon("Lairon"),  Lampent("Lampent"),  Lanturn("Lanturn"),  Lapra

    s("Lapras"),  Larvesta("Larvesta"),  Larvitar("Larvitar"),  Leafeon("Leafeon"),  Leavanny("Leavanny"),  Ledyba("Ledyba"),  Ledian("Ledian"),  Lickitung("Lickitung"),  Litwick("Litwick"),  Lugia("Lugia"),  Lucario("Lucario"),  Lunatone("Lunatone"),  Luxio("Luxio"),  Luxray("Luxray"),  Machamp("Machamp"),  Machoke("Machoke"),  Machop("Machop"),  Magby("Magby"),  Magikarp("Magikarp"),  Magmar("Magmar"),  Magmortar("Magmortar"),  Magnemite("Magnemite"),  Magneton("Magneton"),  Magnezone("Magnezone"),  Mamoswine("Mamoswine"),  Mankey("Mankey"),  Mantine("Mantine"),  Mareep("Mareep"),  Marill("Marill"),  Marowak("Marowak"),  Marshtomp("Marshtomp"),  Meganium("Meganium"),  Meowth("Meowth"),  Metagross("Metagross"),  Metang("Metang"),  Metapod("Metapod"),  Mew("Mew"),  Mewtwo("Mewtwo"),  Miltank("Miltank"),  Minun("Minun"),  Misdreavus("Misdreavus"),  Mismagius("Mismagius"),  Moltres("Moltres"),  Monferno("Monferno"),  MrMime("MrMime"),  Mudkip("Mudkip"),  Muk("Muk"),  Munchlax("Munchlax"),  Murkrow("Murkrow"),  Natu("Natu"),  Nidoking("Nidoking"),  Nidoqueen("Nidoqueen"),  Nidoranfemale("Nidoranfemale"),  Nidoranmale("Nidoranmale"),  Nidorina("Nidorina"),  Nidorino("Nidorino"),  Ninetales("Ninetales"),  Noctowl("Noctowl"),  Numel("Numel"),  Octillery("Octillery"),  Oddish("Oddish"),  Omanyte("Omanyte"),  Omastar("Omastar"),  Onix("Onix"),  Oshawott("Oshawott"),  Pachirisu("Pachirisu"),  Paras("Paras"),  Parasect("Parasect"),  Pawniard("Pawniard"),  Persian("Persian"),  Phanpy("Phanpy"),  Pichu("Pichu"),  Pidgey("Pidgey"),  Pikachu("Pikachu"),  Pidgeotto("Pidgeotto"),  Pidgeot("Pidgeot"),  Pignite("Pignite"),  Piloswine("Piloswine"),  Pineco("Pineco"),  Pinsir("Pinsir"),  Piplup("Piplup"),  Plusle("Plusle"),  Politoed("Politoed"),  Poliwag("Poliwag"),  Poliwhirl("Poliwhirl"),  Poliwrath("Poliwrath"),  Ponyta("Ponyta"),  Porygon("Porygon"),  PorygonZ("Porygon-Z"),  Porygon2("Porygon2"),  Primeape("Primeape"),  Prinplup("Prinplup"),  Psyduck("Psyduck"),  Pupitar("Pupitar"),  Quilava("Quilava"),  Qwilfish("Qwilfish"),  Raichu("Raichu"),  Raikou("Raikou"),  Rampardos("Rampardos"),  Rapidash("Rapidash"),  Raticate("Raticate"),  Rattata("Rattata"),  Rayquaza("Rayquaza"),  Remoraid("Remoraid"),  Reuniclus("Reuniclus"),  Rhydon("Rhydon"),  Rhyhorn("Rhyhorn"),  Rhyperior("Rhyperior"),  Riolu("Riolu"),  Roggenrola("Roggenrola"),  Rufflet("Rufflet"),  Sableye("Sableye"),  Salamence("Salamence"),  Samurott("Samurott"),  Sandile("Sandile"),  Sandshrew("Sandshrew"),  Sandslash("Sandslash"),  Sceptile("Sceptile"),  Scizor("Scizor"),  Scolipede("Scolipede"),  Scyther("Scyther"),  Seadra("Seadra"),  Seaking("Seaking"),  Sealeo("Sealeo"),  Seel("Seel"),  Serperior("Serperior"),  Servine("Servine"),  Sewaddle("Sewaddle"),  Sharpedo("Sharpedo"),  Shelgon("Shelgon"),  Shellder("Shellder"),  Shieldon("Shieldon"),  Shinx("Shinx"),  Shuckle("Shuckle"),  Sigilyph("Sigilyph"),  Skarmory("Skarmory"),  Skorupi("Skorupi"),  Slowbro("Slowbro"),  Slowking("Slowking"),  Slowpoke("Slowpoke"),  Smeargle("Smeargle"),  Snivy("Snivy"),  Sneasel("Sneasel"),  Snorlax("Snorlax"),  Solosis("Solosis"),  Solrock("Solrock"),  Spearow("Spearow"),  Spheal("Spheal"),  Spinarak("Spinarak"),  Squirtle("Squirtle"),  Stantler("Stantler"),  Staraptor("Staraptor"),  Staravia("Staravia"),  Starly("Starly"),  Staryu("Staryu"),  Starmie("Starmie"),  Suicune("Suicune"),  Swablu("Swablu"),  Swadloon("Swadloon"),  Swampert("Swampert"),  Swinub("Swinub"),  Tangela("Tangela"),  Tauros("Tauros"),  Teddiursa("Teddiursa"),  Tentacool("Tentacool"),  Tentacruel("Tentacruel"),  Tepig("Tepig"),  Tirtouga("Tirtouga"),  Torchic("Torchic"),  Torterra("Torterra"),  Totodile("Totodile"),  Trapinch("Trapinch"),  Treecko("Treecko"),  Tropius("Tropius"),  Turtwig("Turtwig"),  Typhlosion("Typhlosion"),  Tyranitar("Tyranitar"),  Tyrogue("Tyrogue"),  Umbreon("Umbreon"),  Ursaring("Ursaring"),  Vaporeon("Vaporeon"),  Venipede("Venipede"),  Venomoth("Venomoth"),  Venonat("Venonat"),  Venusaur("Venusaur"),  Vibrava("Vibrava"),  Victreebel("Victreebel"),  Vileplume("Vileplume"),  Volcarona("Volcarona"),  Voltorb("Voltorb"),  Vulpix("Vulpix"),  Wailmer("Wailmer"),  Wailord("Wailord"),  Wartortle("Wartortle"),  Walrein("Walrein"),  Weavile("Weavile"),  Weedle("Weedle"),  Weepinbell("Weepinbell"),  Weezing("Weezing"),  Whimsicott("Whimsicott"),  Whirlipede("Whirlipede"),  Wigglytuff("Wigglytuff"),  Wobbuffet("Wobbuffet"),  Wynaut("Wynaut"),  Xatu("Xatu"),  Yanma("Yanma"),  Yanmega("Yanmega"),  Zapdos("Zapdos"),  Zoroark("Zoroark"),  Zorua("Zorua"),  Zubat("Zubat");

      public static ArrayList<String> legendaries = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Articuno", "Zapdos", "Moltres", "Mewtwo", "Mew", "Entei", "Raikou", "Suicune", "Ho-Oh", "Ho-oh", "HoOh", "Lugia", "Celebi", "Regirock", "Regice", "Registeel", "Latios", "Latias", "Groudon", "Kyogre", "Rayquaza", "Jirachi", "Deoxys", "Uxie", "Azelf", "Mesprit", "Dialga", "Palkia", "Giratina", "Cresselia", "Darkrai", "Manaphy", "Phione", "Heatran", "Regigigas", "Shaymin", "Arceus", "Victini", "Cobalion", "Terrakion", "Virizion", "Keldeo", "Thundurus", "Tornadus", "Landorus", "Zekrom", "Reshiram", "Kyurem", "Genesect", "Meloetta", "Xerneas", "Yveltal", "Zygarde" }));
      public String name;

      private EnumPokemon(String name)
      {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public static boolean hasPokemon(String name)
      {
        return getFromName(name) != null;
      }

      @Deprecated
      public static EnumPokemon get(String name)
      {
        return getFromName(name);
      }

      public static boolean hasPokemonAnyCase(String name)
      {
        for (EnumPokemon pokemon : ) {
          if (name.replace("-", "").equalsIgnoreCase(pokemon.name.replace("-", ""))) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      public static EnumPokemon contains(String containsString)
      {
        for (EnumPokemon e : ) {
          if (containsString.replace("-", "").contains(e.name.replace("-", "").toLowerCase())) {
            return e;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      public static EnumPokemon getFromDBID(int id)
      {
        Connection con = DatabaseHelper.getConnection();
        try
        {
          Statement stat = con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from PIXELMON where PIXELMONID=" + id);
          if (rs.next()) {
            return getFromName(rs.getString("PIXELMONFULLNAME"));
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
      }

      public static EnumPokemon getFromOrdinal(int ordinal)
      {
        for (EnumPokemon e : ) {
          if (e.ordinal() == ordinal) {
            return e;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      public static EnumPokemon randomPoke()
      {
        return randomPoke(true);
      }

      public static EnumPokemon randomPoke(boolean canBeLegendary)
      {
        int pick = new Random().nextInt(values().length);
        if (!canBeLegendary) {
          while (legendaries.contains(values()[pick].name)) {
            pick = new Random().nextInt(values().length);
          }
        }
        return values()[pick];
      }

      public static EnumPokemon getFromNameAnyCase(String name)
      {
        for (EnumPokemon pokemon : ) {
          if (name.replace("-", "").equalsIgnoreCase(pokemon.name.replace("-", ""))) {
            return pokemon;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      public static EnumPokemon getFromName(String name)
      {
        EnumPokemon[] arrayOfEnumPokemon;
        int i;
        int j;
        try
        {
          if (valueOf(name) != null) {
            return valueOf(name);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          arrayOfEnumPokemon = values();i = arrayOfEnumPokemon.length;j = 0;
        }
        for (; j < i; j++)
        {
          EnumPokemon p = arrayOfEnumPokemon[j];
          if (p.name.replace("-", "").equalsIgnoreCase(name.replace("-", ""))) {
            return p;
          }
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Edit 2: Did the first suggestion but now I have 6 other errors.

```
C:\Users\Frank\eclipse-workspace\EnumPokemon\bin\com\pixelmonmod\pixelmon\enums>javac EnumPokemon.java
EnumPokemon.java:3: error: package com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.database does not exist
import com.pixelmonmod.pixelmon.database.DatabaseHelper;
                                        ^
EnumPokemon.java:47: error: package e does not exist
      if (containsString.replace("-", "").contains(e.name.replace("-", "").toLowerCase())) {
                                                    ^
EnumPokemon.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
        return e;
               ^
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class EnumPokemon
EnumPokemon.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    Connection con = DatabaseHelper.getConnection();
                     ^
  symbol:   variable DatabaseHelper
  location: class EnumPokemon
EnumPokemon.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
      if (e.ordinal() == ordinal) {
          ^
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class EnumPokemon
EnumPokemon.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
        return e;
               ^
  symbol:   variable e
  location: class EnumPokemon
```

Comment: In general its a bold to assume that it is the compiler that is wrong.

Comment: Javac is working fine. The problem is in your code. Unfortunately, we can't see that code from where we are, and it's not included in your post.

Comment: How does your code look? Basically javac is saying that your code is wrong.

Comment: The only reason why i assumed it was because i didnt edit that part of the code and it works fine on the game i was playing.

Comment: Please never ever again post a code example that contains an enum with that many elements. Provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Sorry, once again im new at this programming thing and this website, I dont know much about whats what yet. I was planning to make this my first and hopefully last post.

Answer (score 1):

The following code in not valid Java code. You are missing the iterator that the `for-loop` should iterate.

```
for (EnumPokemon pokemon : ) {
    ...
}
```

I assume that your want iterate the values of `EnumPokemon` your code should look like this.

```
for (EnumPokemon pokemon : EnumPokemon.values()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did that, but got 6 new errors, put it under the first edit

Comment: @NobodyImportant it sounds like you should be reading the [official Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) instead of asking questions on SO. If the compiler tells you that it can't find a symbol you should be looking through your code where you are defining it

Comment: @unholysheep alright but I have one last question then, im going through the error message, then i noticed the first error says that a certain folder doesn't exist when it does, what do i do about that?